# Unable to connect from RHEL SQL Server to Windows SQL Server Linked Instance

Tags: sql-server, rhel

I setup 3 exactly similar Dell rack servers with RHEL 8.3 and Sql Server 15.0.4102.2.  There was an existing windows sql server that I added to all 3 RHEL sql server instances as a linked server using the exact same script on all 3 RHEL sql servers.  2 of the servers work fine, the third fails with the following error message every time:

*Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "remserver" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "MSOLEDBSQL" for linked server "remserver" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*

Port 1433 is open on all 3 and remember 2 of the exactly similar servers work perfectly fine, allowing me to connect to the remote windows linked server just fine.

What I am looking for is some advice as to where I should start debugging things.  A weird thing is that I was able to run Red-Gate's SQL Pro Compare tool to deploy the database from remserver to the 3rd server just fine, so I think Sql Server on the 3rd server is installed correctly.  I just cannot connect to the linked remserver from the 3rd sql server.

Thanks, Don Bouchard

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was trying everything I could think of and I stumbled upon what it was which was because of a DNS misconfiguration.  A simple ping to the remserver name showed me the problem.